# Empty Region in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Why did I get this error message, when I tried to create XML File?

How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Please also add the exception message into your question as **text** so it is searchable for the future.

Comment: Exception Stack Trace `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty region!`  `at javax.imageio.ImageReader.computeRegions(Unknown Source)`  `at com.sun.imageio.plugins.wbmp.WBMPImageReader.read(Unknown Source)`  `at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)`  `at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 2):

While creating xml file if you are referencing any file or image that is corrupted or not supported format by android xml it will give exception like this.